# jquery ajax datatype html ajaxcomplete response undefined

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I write a function to fetch PartialView

```
function  open_Modal ()  {
        $.ajax({
            url: URLRoot,           

            type: "POST",            
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {

                //do something
            }
        });
    }
```

and I also have another method to check between ajax call whether session is lost.

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, xhr, settings) {
    var response = xhr.responseJSON;
    console.log(response)
    try
    {
        if (response.sessionlost != undefined && response.sessionlost.lost == 1) {
            window.location = URLRoot + "/" + response.sessionlost.url;
        }
    }
    catch(ex){}
});
```

I found for  `dataType: "html",` the response is always undefined  `console.log(response)`.but its works when `dataType: "json",`

Any body please give some idea to work for both case.

Comment: What does you controller method return?

Comment: I suspected you have `return Json` in action method with `URLRoot` as the action URL so that data returned as JSON, are you want something like `return Content`?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that if you change dataType that's means you must use the appropriate response type :

If **dataType** is **html**  you can read response by

var response = xhr.responseText;